# Get first Monday and last Sunday of one Month

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, react-datepicker

I use `react-datepicker` lib and I want get first Monday (from date) and last Sunday (to date) of month picker.

Look like example image here (I want detect `from` and `to` date, maybe a function with input is current month and output is `from` and `to` date):

[image]

Note: I use `props` paste from `renderCustomHeader` but dont have any info date I need.

Thank alot for your help.